# How to set true or false in attribute required in PrimeFaces using Java code?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, required

I would like to set in java code value in my xhtml portlet in attribut required.

I'm trying this:

```
  required="{portalProperties.checkRequired(foo)}"
```

Java code

```
public boolean checkRequired(String inputName) {
        if ("foo".equals(inputName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

but my function doesn't invoke. Can somebody tell me how to solve my problem?

Comment: The method names do not match.

Comment: sory but it doesn't a issue.

Comment: it's like this `#{portalProperties.checkRequired('foo')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the hash (#) sign in front of the el expression: #{...}.

Comment: When i use (#) i get error "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Syntax error in EL
 - Expression must be a value expression but is a method "

Comment: Method is invoked but String 'foo' is not passing to function.